# How can I do a editable table in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have created a table using ngTable and all good until I want to be able to edit it.

I have the buttons to edit, to erase and to add but it does not work. No mistake gives me the console. I have copied the example of the API, maybe it is it for what does not work well because I have not could implement it to my code. It is grateful if you put some different example.

```
// SORT TABLE -->
        function refresh(){
            vm.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,            
                count: 10,
                filter: {
                    id: '',
                    curso: '',
                    precio: '',
                    new: '',
                    url_curso: ''
                },
                sorting: {
                    id: 'asc'     
                  }
              },{
                  data: vm.datos
                  }
              );
        }
  //EDIT TABLE

        vm.checkId = function(data, id){
            if (id === 2 && data !== 'awesome'){
                return '';
            }
        };

        vm.saveUser = function(data, id){
            angular.extend(data, {id:id});
            console.log('Saving user: '+id)
        };

        vm.removeUser = function(index){
            vm.test.splice(index,1);
        };

        vm.addUser = function(){
            vm.inserted ={
                id: vm.datos.length+1,
                curso: '',
                precio: null,
                url_curso: '',
                new: true
            };
            vm.datos.push(vm.inserted);
        };
    };
})();
```

Comment: Can you check this example. https://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/UWLFJ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a span with the td

```
<td data-title="'IDCurso'" filter="{id: 'number'}" sortable="'id'">
        <span editable-number="curso.id" e-name="id" e-form="rowform" e-required="">{{curso.id}}</span>
     </td>
```

In the span you'll find that i added the e-* attribute, thats because i use rowform to do it, and you can use that attrs. But first, you'll need to inject xeditable module to do it.

After that, use the example with all your fields changing the values.

When you finish it, you'll modify your buttons, better follow that structure:

```
<form editable-form="" name="rowform" onbeforesave="datos.saveUser($data, curso.id)" ng-show="rowform.$visible" shown="datos.inserted == curso" class="form-buttons form-inline">
           <button type="submit" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" title="Save" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">
              <em class="fa fa-save"></em>
           </button>
           <button type="button" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" ng-click="rowform.$cancel()" title="Cancel" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
              <em class="fa fa-times"></em>
           </button>
        </form>
        <div ng-show="!rowform.$visible" class="buttons">
           <button ng-click="rowform.$show()" title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">
              <em class="fa fa-pencil"></em>
           </button>
           <button ng-click="datos.removeUser($index,curso.id)" title="Delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
              <em class="fa fa-trash"></em>
           </button>
        </div>
```

Change the values you need in your case, and study it to see how it works, you can find the methods of the controller and a lot of more ngTables in this page: 
[enter link description here](http://ng-table.com/#/)

Comment: Thank you. This is all of i need it!

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS MY JS::

```
// SORT TABLE -->
        function refresh(){
            vm.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,            
                count: 10,
                filter: {
                    id: '',
                    curso: '',
                    precio: '',
                    new: '',
                    url_curso: ''
                },
                sorting: {
                    id: 'asc'     
                  }
              },{
                  data: vm.datos
                  }
              );
        }
  //EDIT TABLE

        vm.checkId = function(data, id){
            if (id === 2 && data !== 'awesome'){
                return '';
            }
        };

        vm.saveUser = function(data, id){
            angular.extend(data, {id:id});
            console.log('Saving user: '+id)
        };

        vm.removeUser = function(index){
            vm.test.splice(index,1);
        };

        vm.addUser = function(){
            vm.inserted ={
                id: vm.datos.length+1,
                curso: '',
                precio: null,
                url_curso: '',
                new: true
            };
            vm.datos.push(vm.inserted);
        };
    };


})();
```